# Can't locate .js (or .css) files from a .jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am running Tomcat 5.54 app server from Eclipse Indigo under Windows 7 Ultimate.  My servlet is using a .jsp and the .jsp page contains (among others) the following to "include" some JavaScript into the .jsp:

When the servlet runs the .jsp page is displayed but I get 404 errors like "The requested resource (/MyServer/WebContent/WEB-INF/JSP/Scripts/Modernizr-2.5.3.js) is not available." on all of the .js and .css files that are included in the .jsp page.

The relevant file locations are:
./WEB-INF/JSP           the .jsp file
./WEB-INF/JSP/Scripts       the .js file
./WEB-INF/JSP/CSS       the .css files

In particular, Modernizr-2.5.3.js is located (as managed by Eclipse) at .\Projects\MyServer\WebContent\WEB-INF\JSP\Scripts\Modernizr-2.5.3.js.  I understand that the path to "included" content such as .js, .css, images and such is relative to the location of the submitted URL, not relative to the displayed .jsp and it is my understanding that the best way to handle this is to use a fully qualified path in the src= URL, which I believe I am doing.  However, I get 404 errors.  I have tried placing Modernizr-2.5.3.js (as a test case) "all over the place" and I have never been able to eliminate the 404 errors.  (I realize I can pull this particular script from the web but that doesn't solve the problem that I have.)

Do I have a mistake in the src= URL?  If not, what else would cause these 404 errors?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What src URL are you using? What is the URL of the page you've requested? And can you get to the hs or CSS directly by entering its path into the browser address bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WEB-INF isn't available publicly. It is usually used to store you JSP and library files and descriptors.  If you want to reference your javascript and css resources without having to go through some dispatcher that loads them from the classpath (i.e. you want to reference them like a regular web resource) they should be in some other directory outside of WEB-INF.

So I would suggest creating `Projects/MyServer/WebContent/js` and `Projects/MyServer/WebContent/css` and put your js and css in the appropriate folder.  Then the src attribute can point to /js/Modernizr-2.5.3.js and /css/mycss.css

Comment: Thanks DigitalJoe, as I said to Dmitry above, I find it strange that something called "WEB-INF" (as in maybe "Web Info") can't contain web accessible resources.  Your specific paths helped me to get clear on where things go and I'm now up and running/

Answer (score 1):

WEB-INF is for classes and property files it should not be used for JSPs and other linkabale resources. You should move your files in to the root of your web app or another directory under it.

Comment: Thanks DMitry, but I find it strange that something called "WEB-INF" (as in maybe "Web Info") can't contain web accessible resources!